# This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer'

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

If a message was sent to a topic in a different format, for example, not JSON as I expect, but String, then we cannot deserialize it.

Please tell me how to ignore such messages.

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    public KafkaConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ExternalCardServiceData> kafkaContainerFactory() {
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, ExternalCardServiceData> consumerFactory =
                new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
                        new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(ExternalCardServiceData.class));
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ExternalCardServiceData> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${topic}'}",
        groupId = "#{'${groupid}'}",
        autoStartup = "#{'${enabled}'}",
        containerFactory = "kafkaContainerFactory")
public void updateExternalCardToken(ConsumerRecord<String, ExternalCardServiceData> record) {
    try {
        ExternalCardServiceData externalCardServiceData = record.value();
        String key = record.key();
        log.info("ExternalCardsListener. Received message: {}, offset={}", externalCardServiceData, record.offset());
        externalCardService.updateToken(key, externalCardServiceData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error processing message received from kafka. [Message={}]", record.value());
        externalCardService.saveTokensErrors(record.key(), record.value().toString(),
                Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates; you need to configure an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` which will catch the exception and the failed record will be sent straight to the error handler.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer